# OBIA following connected components segmentation in Monteverdi2

Tags: classification, feature-extraction, orfeo-toolbox

New to Monteverdi2 and OTB. I just finished a connected components segmentation using the Segmentation module and the large-scale vector output mode for large datasets. How can I filter the output (now a shp file) using an OBIA Expression like that available in the Connected Components module? Do I rasterize the shp? I don't see an OBIA module that starts from such a raster--only the integrated CC segmentation and OBIA tool that I couldn't use because my dataset is too large. Maybe I'm missing something. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you explain/include links to your abbreviations?

Comment: Sorry. OTB = Orfeo Toolbox, the freeware set of remote sensing tools, and OBIA = object-based image analysis.

Comment: When you said finished: CC segmentation. You mean finish execution of otbcli_LSMSVectorization?. You can try otbcli_ConnectedComponentSegmentation for OBIA. see cookbook section - http://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/CookBooksu119.html

Comment: Hey there,
In fact, I've gone ahead and figured out another way to go in Erdas Imagine Objective. Thanks.